# sending logs to logstash via http input from node application

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

i have elk  setup in linux machine and i have been hosted my node application into same machine. Now i want to send my node application logs via http input or restful api to logstash. anyone has idea about it ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not dumping your node logs to a file and let Logstash tail them? It's not a good idea to synchronously send your logs via HTTP. What if Logstash is down for some reason? What if Logstash is slow for some reason? Your node app would suffer for no reason.

Comment: thanks for your reply Val. whatever you said is perfect and awesome. but i have one more question i.e. i want to maintain that http method in each and every function  asychronously and i want to  store logs in file too and then i will send those to logstash. is it good  ??? please let me know if my thought is bad . and sorry for my stupid english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use [logstash-input-http](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html) plugin?

in logstash.conf

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 8080
  }
}
```

Comment: No buddy , can you explain  how to configure it in node application ??

Comment: first, you should install logstash-input-http plugin and set this on logstash conf, after this,
you can send http post request to logstash using logstash machin's ip.

var request = require('request');

request.post(
    "http:/logstashIP:8080",
    { data: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);

Comment: hai yountae , do i want to install logstash-input-http in both linux machine and in my node application ???

Comment: hai youtae do you know how to install logstash-input-http on centos ?? i didn't find command to install that.

Comment: find your logstash path, something like "/usr/share/logstash/bin/" goto this folder and execute logstash-plugin install logstash-input-http

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with with @val , its not ideal to write to Logstash http 
Add message brokers like Kafka in between, which can help you, and Logstash can read from kafka

Comment: thanks to you bro . is there any chance to create a http method  that has to be call in each and every functionality and those logs should be go to the our application file and then logstash.